# Mixed fraction input

Tags: front-end, formatting, input

How do I make mathematica treat $5\frac{1}{2}$ as a mixed fraction rather than 5 times one-half?

I'm using typesetting keyboard shortcuts (if that's important)

Currently I'm using $(5 + \frac{1}{2})$ to achieve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add an input alias to do this. For example:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "mf"}] = TemplateBox[
    {"\[SelectionPlaceholder]","\[Placeholder]","\[Placeholder]"},
    "MixedFraction",
    DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{#1, FractionBox[#2,#3]}]&),
    InterpretationFunction->(RowBox[{#1,"+", FractionBox[#2,#3]}]&)
];
```

Here is a short animation showing it in action:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[`\[ImplicitPlus]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/ImplicitPlus.html) can be entered as <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>:

```
5\[ImplicitPlus](1/2)
(*  11/2  *)
```

It works for entering in the Front End, but it is automatically converted to `Plus`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]