# How to write mixed fraction in text cell?

Tags: notebooks, text-formatting

I could not find any especial typesetting for mixed fractions in Pallets.

In text cell, when I put fraction $\frac{1}{2}$ and after put $5%$ in front of it it automatically becomes $5 * \frac{1}{2}$.

How do I make Mathematica display $5\frac{1}{2}$ in text cell?

Comment: possible duplicate Q/A: [Mixed fraction input](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184781/125)

Comment: @kglr No. My question is about mixed numbers in the text cell. The question in your link is about input cell.

Comment: vasili111, if you replace `DisplayFunction -> ...` in Carl's answer with `DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{#1, "\[ImplicitPlus]",  FractionBox[#2, #3]}] &)` you can also use the alias "mf" in text cells and input cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Row[{5, 1/2}]
```

$$5\frac{1}{2}$$

Using [`\[ImplicitPlus\]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/character/ImplicitPlus.html.en) to write it in text cell press <kbd>5</kbd>, press <kbd>esc</kbd>, press <kbd>+</kbd>, press <kbd>esc</kbd>, press <kbd>1</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> together with <kbd>/</kbd>, press <kbd>2</kbd>:

<kbd>5</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>ctrl+/</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is not working in the text cell. I need to write mixed fraction in the text cell.

Comment: @vasili111: I added how to do it.

Comment: Thank you. That works. Solved.

Comment: It seems second variant also works in Input cell. What for is this shortcut `ESC` `+` `ESC`? What it instructs to do to Mathematica?

Comment: @vasili111: https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/character/ImplicitPlus.html.en

Comment: Thank you. This is the link that will point to always latest version: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/ImplicitPlus.html

Comment: @vasili111 On implicit plus: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184781/mixed-fraction-input/189145#189145